# Cannot install nasm on my Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nasm

I've tried to install nasm using: sudo apt-get install nasm, but I got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know what goes wrong here as I new with Ubuntu/Linux OS

Comment: Try what the output suggests: `apt-get -f install nasm`

Comment: I've tried it and get the following:

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Yes, run the above command as root: `sudo apt-get -f install nasm`

Comment: Got the following:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.8-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: See my second comment. You run the command with `sudo` at the front, which will then attempt to run the command following `sudo` as root, after you've successfully typed in your password.

Comment: Oh sorry, it suggests running `apt-get -f install` with no package name. So do: `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766248/16320782

Answer (score 1):

Your package manager has noticed that some of your packages, even though they're installed, have prerequisites that aren't. This seems to be the reason `nasm` is not working.

This happens sometimes. Luckily, you can instruct `apt-get` to automatically fetch and install the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The `sudo` prefix will run the command as the `root` user, giving it the elevated permissions it needs to install software. You can think of `sudo` as "Super User DO", or "Switch User and DO".

Comment: Still not working. Got the following: Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/timerfd.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the 32/64 bit versions of `libc`. Try removing it, the package manager may correct the problem automatically. Run `sudo dpkg --remove libc6-dev-amd64`, see what happens. Retry `apt-get -f install` if necessary

Comment: sudo dpkg --remove libc6-dev-amd64  Solved my issue